# ¿Cómo relacionar un modelo con él mismo? rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Hola amigos de StackOverflow. Quiero conectar un modelo consigo mismo (**group**), usando una referencia a un modelo inexistente que apunte al modelo grupo (**branch**), a través de otro modelo (**tree**), es decir una relacion has_many through.

group.rb:

```
class Group < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :trees
  has_many :branches, through: :trees, class_name: Tree.to_s
end
```

tree.rb:

```
class Tree < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :group
  belongs_to :branch, class_name: Group.to_s
end
```

Pero cuando ejecuto: `Tree.create group:Group.first, branch:Group.second`, obtengo este error:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: SQLite3::SQLException: no such table: main.branches: INSERT INTO "trees" ("group_id", "branch_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)
```

Creo que dice que no encuentra el modelo **branch**, pero le estoy diciendo que si busca a ese modelo, que vaya a **group**.
¿Qué hago mal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esta solución vino a mi solo porque sí, no la encontré en ninguna documentación:

1) Se crea el modelo que se quiere enlazar, en este caso `Group`
2) Se crea el modelo intermedio:

`rg model Tree group:references branch_id:integer`

Donde rg es un alias de `rails generate`, y group hace referencia al modelo recién creado, adicionalmente un campo nombre_id (**branch_id** en este caso) tipo entero, que es el campo que guardará las ids de las relaciones.

`rails db:migrate` o `rdm` con el plugin de rails del **Oh-My-ZSH**

Y ya en el modelo **Tree** ponemos:

```
class Tree < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :group
  belongs_to :branch, class_name: "Group"
end
```

Y en el modelo **Group**

```
class Group < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :trees, foreign_key: :group_id
    has_many :branches, through: :trees, source: :branch
end
```

Cuando abran la consola de rails ejecuten:

```
Group.create name:"Grupo1"
Group.create name:"Grupo2"
Tree.create group:Group.first, branch:Group.second
Group.first.branch_ids
```

Answer (score 0):

Al modelo branch indicale que la tabla a la que referencia es group de la siguiente manera `self.table_name = 'groups'`. Si no me equivoco los tres modelos hacen referencia a la misma tabla. Por lo tanto es necesario indicarlo también en el modelo Tree. He indicar en las relaciones el foreign_key

```
class Tree < ApplicationRecord
  self.table_name = 'groups'
  belongs_to :group
  has_many :branches, foreign_key: :group_id
end

class Group < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :trees, foreign_key: :group_id
  has_many :branches, through: :trees
end

class Branch < ApplicationRecord
  self.table_name = 'groups'
  belongs_to :tree
end
```

Comment: El modelo branch no existe, porque quiero que el modelo tree guarde a los grupos en ambos campos, por eso es que digo que quiero relacionar al grupo con el mismo

Comment: Tree solo funciona como una tabla intermedia para guardar las relaciones. :)